# TextWriterTraceListener writes app filename.exe on beginning on each line

Tags: c#, logging, customization, trace

I'm using my own custom TextWriterTraceListener for adding timestamp to each logged line so that the output looks like this:

```
  LoggingExperiments.exe Information: 0 : 13:11 Testing infos
  LoggingExperiments.exe Error: 0 : 13:11   Testing errors
```

Here is the code:

```
class CustomTextWriterTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
{
    public CustomTextWriterTraceListener(string file) : base(file) 
    {            
    }        

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {            
        base.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        base.Write("\t");
        base.WriteLine(message); // #1
        Writer.WriteLine(message); // #2
    }
}
```

How to format the output so that it doesn't have leading executable names on each line? Or to change the order of information logged?

Should I always call "Writer.WriteLine" and format it's parameters (comment #2) or there is some other way to override this behavior and stay with calling base methods like in code marked as #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce your behavior... 
I've tried this code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;

namespace TraceExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CustomTraceListener c = new CustomTraceListener("log.txt");
            Trace.Listeners.Add(c);
            Trace.WriteLine("WriteLine","Info");
            Trace.Flush();
        }
    }

    public class CustomTraceListener : TextWriterTraceListener
    {
        public CustomTraceListener(string file) : base(file){}    
        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            base.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            base.Write("\t");
            base.WriteLine(message); // #1
            Writer.WriteLine(message); // #2
        }
    }
}
```

And Output is :

You can do in configuration file :

```
17.02   Info: WriteLine
Info: WriteLine



<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="consoleListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" 
          traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Take a look at **traceOutputOptions**

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a10k7w6c.aspx) the MSDN reference

Comment: The result of such operation is not what I really want to achieve. Setting TraceOutputOptions to bitwise combination of ProcessId and DateTime (here as an example only) makes new lines with ProcessId and DateTime logged to the file. What I'd like to achieve is getting rid of "LoggingExperiments.exe" that is written at the beginning of each log line - please see my first post as I've updated formatting for log output.

Comment: take a look at this example : http://olondono.blogspot.com/2008/01/about-trace-listeners.html
TraceListener already have a TimeStamp. 
If you want more flexibility you may consider to use Log4net... very powerfull and easy to use.

Comment: The example you mention doesn't bring any news here for me. I've already tried with TraceOutputOptions configured the way it is done there - with no luck, so TraceOutputOptions isn't the solution here. I would rather like to know how to override the default TraceListener's class behavior of writing the file.exe at the beginning of each line.

Comment: OK - finally, after comparing your code against mine I've found that you're using "Trace.WriteLine("WriteLine","Info");" to log trace messages, while I do it in my code this way: "Trace.TraceInformation("WriteLine 2");". So it seems that only the TraceInformation-like methods add this extra information on the beginning of the lines. I could have sent my code including Main function... Nevertheless - now that I know the difference I will handle it your way - thank you for support.